# Anylogic: How to create multiple orders at one moment?

Tags: action, anylogic, schedule, orders, agent

I have created a schedule in Anylogic within the population of agents "customer", where customers have to create orders and send it to "terminals". Every day, the amount of orders that has to be send to terminals is different for every customer. I want to create multiple orders at once (every day, that is the *start* column within the schedule), and the amount I want to create is the *value* column within the schedule. How to do this?

As you can see below, now just one order is created every day (with the amount as parameter), but I want to create this amount of orders at that one day/moment. Thank you for the help!

[image: Schedule]

The schedule data looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please show a screenshot of how the schedule data looks like.

Comment: Thank you, I added a screenshot of the schedule data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

[image: example]

You will have to set the parameters of your agent in the source and on the exit block you do `send(agent,main.terminals(0))`

If you have missing data instead of 0 in your value, use this in your agents per arrival:

[image]

```
selectFrom(db_table)
    .where(db_table.name.eq(name))
    .where(db_table.start.eq(getDayOfWeek()-1))
    .count()>0

?

selectFrom(db_table)
    .where(db_table.name.eq(name))
    .where(db_table.start.eq(getDayOfWeek()-1))
    .uniqueResult(db_table.value, int.class)
 :
 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried it but I get an error since there are some "empty database values", as some days for some customers, the amount of orders to be made is 0. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I added the code you need to add to the main answer @Ella

Answer (score 1):

I would add dates to my schedule data, such as 28-12-2021 15:28. Then type something big into the `Repeat every` section. This is how I do it (my unit is always 1, but you can have any number instead):

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with _something big_ in the `Repeat every` section

Comment: Like 365, so if your simulation is run for 1 year, you will not have repeating schedule.

Comment: But how can I create multiple orders at one moment? (so if the unit is for example 8), how can I create 8 orders in the `Action` field?

Comment: The number of agents to be created is defined by the `value` column. If you want to generate them one-by-one, you need to loop through it. `getValue()` will give you the number of units for that moment and you can loop until that value is reached and create your orders.

Comment: Oh you think the amount of orders is made automatically by the `value` column if the action is `Order order = new Order(customer, terminal)`? I got the feeling when running the model that only 1 order was made per day (instead of the _value_  amount of orders), but I could be wrong.

Comment: Or if you use Source block with scheduled arrivals, it will create that many agents.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240498/discussion-between-ella-and-yashar-ahmadov).